# Why DocuSign asks to sign the Disclosures if all signers have completed signing

Tags: api, email, templates, docusignapi, docusignconnect

The DocuSign sends a mail to the signers once the signing is completed. But In that email template, it says please sign the Disclosures. Is there any particular reason for that? Please find below a screenshot of the email template. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UJE6.png)

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The email from DocuSign starts with "All signers completed"  and then adds the subject email that was provided for this envelope. In your case "Please sign the Disclosure below".

This logic to concatenate the text probably needs to be fixed, and you can provide that
feedback@docusign.com but has nothing to do with using the DocuSign API.